# How to install and configure FreeBSD without internet access?

Tags: freebsd, system-installation

After installing FreeBSD we would like to use following commands to install additional packages.

```
pkg
pkg install nano
pkg install xorg
pkg install mate-desktop mate
pkg install slim
```

The above commands require an Internet connection to install packages. But how can we install those packages *without* an Internet connection by using CD/DVD/USB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based upon [an open issue](https://www.freebsd.org/releases/10.1R/errata/#open-issues) in *FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE Errata*:

1. Create a `/dist` directory, then mount the DVD.

   ```
   # mkdir -p /dist
   # mount -t cd9660 /dev/cd0 /dist
   ```
2. Make sure `REPOS_DIR` is correctly pointing to your local repository. For [sh(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD):

   ```
   # export REPOS_DIR=/dist/packages/repos
   ```

   – or, for [csh(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=csh&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD):

   ```
   # setenv REPOS_DIR /dist/packages/repos
   ```
3. Use [pkg(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=7&manpath=FreeBSD) to bootstrap [pkg(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD-Ports), then install packages.

   ```
   # pkg bootstrap --yes
   # pkg install xorg [...]
   ```

#### Limitations of -dvd1.iso files

`FreeBSD-13.1-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso` does not provide packages for `mate`, `mate-desktop`, `nano`, or `slim`.

Comment: FreeBSD-10.1-RELEASE-i386-dvd1 i use it....

Comment: mount -t cd9660 /dev/cd0 /dist that not show anything and export REPOS_DIR=/dist/packages/repos it shows error :- E: export command not found.

Comment: @MadhavNikam Is the DVD in the machine? You need to insert it before attempting to mount it. If the `export` failed, you must be using `csh`, so use `setenv` instead.

Comment: DVD is in machine. csh worked. now again one think ;;; pkg install xorg-server xorg gnome2 after that one msg shows:- The process will require 2 GB more space. 511 MB to be downloaded. It still require internet?

Comment: sorry its worked.. :)

Comment: actually your answers fulfills all requirements but i still want some extra... after that How to enable graphical login and user interface.

Comment: @MadhavNikam As that's separate from your original question, please create a new question.

Answer (score -1):

Just to share my observation on this:

On FreeBSD 11.1, I run `$ sudo bsdconfig` and go to `packages` menu item. Then I select the first item which is `CD/DVD`. Then I select `cd0` as my device, but I receive the following error:

> No pkg(8) database found!

[image]

However, the procedure suggested by @mjturner works fine.

Comment: FreeBSD bug [201485 – bsdconfig no pkg database found](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201485)