# Can I install GUI from the DVD-ISO's FreeBSD without internet?

Tags: freebsd

Can I install GUI in FreeBSD from DVD installation ISO. I haven't internet for downloading files for FreeBSD, maybe there's another way for solve this problem? Please tell me what do I need to do ?

Comment: yes . https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215699/how-to-install-and-configure-freebsd-without-internet-access

Comment: FYI: Some BSD releases automatically install a GUI. For example, [Project Trident](http://www.project-trident.org/) and [GhostBSD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GhostBSD).

Comment: Are there any 32 bit OS?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, DVD images come with some packages ready to be installed. Use `bsdconfig packages` to install them using console GUI.

Comment: This method might blocked by FreeBSD bug [201485 – bsdconfig no pkg database found](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201485).